# FFMPEG and Newtek NDI

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, live-streaming, ndi

I have a ffmpeg bash script which currently runs a command to stream RTMP output.
Is there a way to output an NDI stream using ffmpeg?

Thank you.

Comment: Newtek ran afoul of FFmpeg licensing terms and did not resolve concerns in a way that satisfied the group.  Therefore, Newtek NDI was removed from FFmpeg.  I think someone was working on an open source module compatible with NDI.  Alternatively, there is NDI support in Gstreamer.